# how do you ignore empty cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

I'm using this function to rank data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11>B2) / COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,$B$2:$B$11&"")) + 1
```

This version assigns 1 to the highest value
and sequentially increasing ranks to lower numbers.
(It can be reversed, to rank from low to high.)
I'm using this formula so that the ranks don't skip numbers when there are duplicates. For example, if the highest three values are 44, 44, and 42, with a (two-way) tie for highest, I want the ranks to be 1, 1, and 2, rather than 1, 1, and 3.

The problem is that it treats empty cells as if they contain zero.
How do I stop this formula from ranking the empty cells? For example,
column G shows what I get from the above formula, and column W shows what I want:

```
 B        G      W
22        5      5
(empty)   6      (empty)
44        3      3
55        2      2
55        2      2
66        1      1
33        4      4
66        1      1
```

Comment: Please don't shout. All-caps is hard to read - and hard to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add a conditional query on the front of your formula:

```
=IF(B2<>"",SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11>B2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,$B$2:$B$11&"")),"")
```

So if B2 is not empty, then do your formula. Else leave it blank.

Comment: Note: all this does is suppress the display of the rank for `B` cells that are empty. It still treats empty cells as zeroes, so if you configure the formula to go from low to high, assigning 1 to the lowest value and counting up, then 22, (empty), 44 will get 2, (empty), 3, because the empty data (`B`) cell still got evaluated as 0 and assigned rank 1.